# What values do I need to change in android studio so that a copy of one of my apps shows as a unique app on my phone?

Tags: android, copy

I'm fairly new to android development have been working on an app - anyway I have made a copy of this app as I want to use it for a different purpose. 
What values do I need to change in Android studio for the app to appear unique on my phone (so that it doesn't override the other app when I install it?)

I cant seem to find this same question anywhere.

Thanks in advance, Jack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the package name unique, like com.example.app and com.example.app.beta can be 2 identical apps with the same app name but are still considered as 2 different apps by the android system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Do I need to change the package name wherever it is used in the program, or simply just the package="name.etc" ?

Comment: If your using Android Studio can change the `applicationId` in the defaultConfig clojure or the buildtype or flavor clojure.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit green, But I cant seem to find either of these? Are they supposed to be included in the manifest?

Comment: No. in the build.gradle file. BTW alot of info can be found here, http://developer.android.com/training/index.html